# How to leave user profiles even when there are several pages?

Tags: 7, views, theming

The profiles of my users have several fields (bio etc.) and several pages which I add with views (following, followers etc.).

I try to leave the profiles of users even when we change page, a little as here :

https://disqus.com/by/iamfrancisyo/ (when you click "followers", the information of the user remain posted at the head of page (avatar etc.)).

Yet, the profile disappears when we change page.

I tried to add the variable $tab to user-profile.tpl.php, but naturally it also disappears during the change of page.

Have you a solution?

Comment: Try embedding your views with the [Quick Tabs](https://www.drupal.org/project/quicktabs) module. You probably have the views on sub paths of user/ which then is a new page altogether. You can also use Display Suite or Panels if you wish. Or add the user profile as a attachment at the top of each view via Views 9asuming that User is the base table of the lot)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way:

For each View (which would have User as base table no doubt and which has uid as contextual filter) you add an attachment View Display and pin it to the top of the main view. In that attachment, under 'Format: Show:' you select to show 'User' instead of 'fields', using the same view mode that is shown for the normal profile.

Comment: Thanks J. Reynolds, I had not thought of this nevertheless simple solution.